# What does "rough" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He just want to rough me and eat food.

I searched online dictionaries for [rough](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rough) as a verb but there is not any meaning fits with that sentence well.

So could you please tell me what the meaning is here?

The fuller text is here:

> Me and Morufu, we don’t talk much. He is always so busy with his
> farming and taxi-driving work from early morning till night.
> Sometimes, he will call me to his room, make me to stand in his front
> with my hand in my back, and ask me question as if he a doctor. He
> will ask me if I am having pregnants yet or if my monthly visitor have
> come because he want me to quick and carry pregnants and born a boy,
> but most times, **he just want to rough** me and eat food. I keep to
> drinking the drink Khadija make for me, from a dark bottle full of
> bitter leafs and ginger. When it is my turn with Morufu, I will take a
> quick cap of it, go to his room, and watch him swallow his own
> Fire-Cracker, before I am making myself a dead body **so that he can
> rough me**. I am hoping that maybe after six months or something like
> that, he will see that no pregnant is ever coming, and he can send me
> go back to my papa. Maybe.

*The girl with louding voice* by Abi Dare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is written by a Nigerian about life in Nigeria. It may be written in *Nigerian Standard English*. Some words will be slang that is particular to that dialect and unlikely to appear in British / American English dictionaries.

From the context, '*rough*' appears to mean 'have sex with' based on the fact she talks about allowing a boy to do this to her in order to get pregnant.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of rough as a verb is “to subject to abuse” as you can find the meaning from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rough)’s dictionary.

> 1 : ROUGHEN
> 2a : to subject to abuse : MANHANDLE, BEAT —usually used with up
> b : to subject to unnecessary and intentional violence in a sport
> a penalty for roughing the passer
> c : SHELL sense 3 —used with up
> was roughed up for six runs
> 3 : to calk or otherwise roughen (a horse's shoes) to prevent slipping
> 4a : to shape, make, or dress in a rough or preliminary way
> b : to indicate the chief lines of
> rough out the structure of a building
> rough it
> : to live under harsh or primitive conditions

I’m not very familiar to the context of the paragraph as I haven’t read the full novel but my guess is that the verb rough here means to sexually abuse because he wants a baby that badly!